# Access static files (js/css..) HapiJS, EJS, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ejs, hapi.js

When using routes, like (http://localhost:port/foo/bar), in the view, in my case an ejs, do i need to declare the full path in the view, to load css/js/images ?

**Vide**: https://github.com/poeticninja/hapi-ninja

**hapi-ninja/server/base/index.js**

```
...
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/foo/bar',
  config: {
    handler: function(request, reply){
      reply.view('about', {
        title: 'Super Informative About Page'
      });
    },
    id: 'about'
  }
},
...
```

ex:
**foot.ejs**

```
<!-- Include the JS -->
<% if (assets.js.length) { %>
    <% assets.js.forEach(function(js){ %>
        <script src="<%=js%><%=version.cache%>"></script>
    <% }) %>
<% } %>
```

Cause, every time i try to load, it gets the relative path (http://localhost:port/foo/bar/js/script.js).

Comment: evidence points to yes, but it always depends on the url path used to request the page relative to the assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by the creator himself:

**First solution:**

[**@poeticninja** commented 4 hours ago](https://gist.github.com/favasconcelos/7f3c94002812f8504c39#gistcomment-1584863)
In your assets file make the paths /js/script.js and not js/script.js. That will fix your problem.

**Other 'solution':**

In the **assets.js**

```
// assets to be used by the 'hapi-assets' module based on process.env.NODE_ENV
module.exports = {
    development: {
        js: ['js/jquery-2.1.4.js', 'js/bootstrap.js'],
        css: ['css/bootstrap.css', 'css/bootstrap-theme.css', 'css/3-col-portfolio.css'],
        host: 'http://development:PORT/'
    },
    production: {
        // TODO: Add the resources minified.
        js: ['js/jquery-2.1.4.js', 'js/bootstrap.js'],
        css: ['css/bootstrap.css', 'css/bootstrap-theme.css', 'css/3-col-portfolio.css'],
        host: 'http://production:PORT/'
    }
}
```

and in the **view**:

```
<script src="<%=assets.host%><%=js%><%=version.cache%>"></script>
```

But, with the initial '/', is better.